# In GitHub, is there a filter I can use to see admin activity in the Audit log?

Tags: audit, github

Is there a specific search filter I can use to see all admin activity in the Audit log in GitHub?

I'm specifically looking for admin changes to repository merge checks and any instance of an admin overriding merge checks in order to merge a PR. Is there a list of actions I can search for somewhere (I can't find this in GitHub's documentation)?

Bonus question: is there any way to send reports or alerts on these events? This could be emails, Slack integration, etc.